# add item to arrayobject with a form

Tags: php, forms, list, object, arrayobject

for better understanding i describe my task.
We have to create a tool in php to add mobile phones with a form into a list one by one. Later the list should be exportet to a CSV/XML file. this is done with an Arrayobject. My problem is that i can enter mobiles with the form, but they will get overridden and not added. So i only have one phone at a time in my list. my code so far:
HTML:

```
      <div>
    <form name="Eingabe" action="handler.php" method="POST">
        <label for="Hersteller">Hersteller</label>
        <input id="Hersteller" name="Hersteller" type="text"><br>
        <label for="Modell">Modell</label>
        <input id="Modell" name="Modell" type="text"><br>
        <label for="Preis">Preis</label>
        <input id="Preis" name="Preis" type="number" min="1" max="1000"><br>
        <label for="Seriennummer">Seriennummer</label>
        <input id="Seriennummer" name="Seriennummer" type="text"><br>
        <br>
        <input name="Senden" type="submit" value="Speichern">
    </form>
  </div>
```

List:

```
    <?php


class handy /* extends guid */ {

    private $id;
    private $hersteller;
    private $modell;
    private $seriennr;
    private $preis;

    public function setid($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function sethersteller($hersteller)
    {
        $this->hersteller = $hersteller;
    }

    public function setmodell($modell)
    {
        $this->modell = $modell;
    }

    public function setseriennr($seriennr)
    {
        $this->seriennr = $seriennr;
    }

    public function setpreis($preis)
    {
        $this->preis = $preis;
    }

    public function getid()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function gethersteller()
    {
        return $this->hersteller;
    }

    public function getmodell()
    {
        return $this->modell;
    }

    public function getseriennr()
    {
        return $this->seriennr;
    }

    public function getpreis()
    {
        return $this->preis;
    }

}

?>
<?php
class handyliste extends ArrayObject {

public function addhandy($i, $hdy)
{
    $this->offsetSet($i, $hdy);
}
?>
```

Handler:

```
        $h = new handy();
    $h->sethersteller($_POST['Hersteller']);
    $h->setid(uniqid());
    $h->setmodell($_POST['Modell']);
    $h->setpreis($_POST['Preis']);
    $h->setseriennr($_POST['Seriennummer']);
    $hl = new handyliste();
    $hl->addhandy(null, $h);
 echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Hersteller</th><th>Modell</th><th>Seriennummer</th><th>Preis</th></tr></thead>";
    foreach ($hl as $h)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $h->getid() . "</td><td>";
        echo $h->gethersteller() . "</td><td>";
        echo $h->getmodell() . "</td><td>";
        echo $h->getseriennr() . "</td><td>";
        echo $h->getpreis() . "€</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

i hope someone can help. with a normal array it would be easy i think, but i never worked with arrayobjects before.

Comment: Excuse me... but if you send only 1 data a time is it normal that you will have only 1 Object inside your arrayobject no?

Comment: thats why i ask. i want to add them one by one with the form respectively thats the task.

Comment: You can save them (temporary) to Sessions or Dbs or File on web space, otherwise each time the array will start empty

Comment: and how do i save it to the session? just asked and got the information to do it w/o DBs, but later export it to CSV/XML

Answer (score 0):

You do have something like:

```
$hl = new handyliste();
```

Now, at the end of your code, after you populate the data you can do something like:

```
$_SESSION['hl'] = $hl;
```

To use the sessions you need to have on top of your code the line:

```
session_start();
```

The will start or continue a session.
Now, before doing

```
$hl = new handyliste();
```

You need to check with something like:

```
$hl = $_SESSION['hl'];
```

And only add elements, you can if not working, cast the list (example), this will save on sessions, and you can see this vars on each page that has got (session_start();) for more info on sessions please refer to php.net

Comment: tried to implement it, but i think i missed something 'cause it wont work. Session_start() is at the very beginning, then i got `$h->setseriennr($_POST['Seriennummer']);
        $_SESSION['hl'] = $hl;
        $hl = $_SESSION['hl'];
        $hl = new handyliste();`

Comment: do not use $hl = new . This will overwrite, after loading use count (or what you use) to check the size, if > 0 do not use new, but try to add elements to it

Comment: maybe my logic is wrong but i use it like this `if (count($hl) <= 0) {
        $hl = new handyliste();
        }
        else {
        $hl = $_SESSION['hl'];        
        }
        $_SESSION['hl'] = $hl;
        $hl->addhandy(null, $h);`
first i populate my $h, then i check if $hl is empty or not, if it is, then create a new list, if not, get session variables. then i think i have to add the data to the list and then add everything to the session.

Comment: is it possible for $hl to be not empty if not before fetched from sessions?

Comment: for the first time the file is opened not, after that the session variables should be loaded, right?

Comment: only if fetched before used :) so, better fetch it and check to use only 1 code for both case